# How to write a value to a memory address in python using a T32_WriteMemory function

Tags: python, trace32

I am trying to automate the Trace32 functions using python. And I am trying to write a value to a memory address using T32_WriteMemory() function. Can someone help me how to go ahead with this function?

Below is the reference from the T32 Api pdf (api_remote.pdf):

```
int T32_WriteMemory(
   uint32_t  byteAddress
   int       access,
   uint8_t  *buffer,
   int       byteSize
);
```

byteAddress : target memory address to start write

access : memory access specifier

buffer : output

byteSize : number of bytes to read

Answer (score 6):

To write memory from a python script via TRACE32 do the following:

1. Enable the port for remote control at TRACE32
2. Get the compiled shared libraries for TRACE32 remote access (t32api.dll/.so)
3. Load the t32api library in your python script (using ctypes)
4. Connect via the t32api library to your TRACE32 GUI
5. Declare the parameter types of T32_WriteMemory
6. Create a byte buffer with the data to write in your target endianness
7. Call the T32_WriteMemory from the t32api library (using ctypes)
8. Close the connection to TRACE32 before ending your script

In detail:

**1. Enable the port for remote control at TRACE32**

Add the following lines to your TRACE32 configuration file (config.t32):

```
RCL=NETASSIST
PORT=20000
```

There must be an empty line before and after that block. Of course you can also choose an other number for port. A TRACE32 GUI started with these setting opens a UDP/IP port to listen for possible requests to remote control TRACE32.

**2. Get the compiled shared libraries for TRACE32 remote access**

You'll find the required shared libraries in your TRACE32 installation at `<T32>/demo/api/capi/dll` (On Windows this is usually C:\t32\demo\api\capi\dll) You can also download it at http://www.lauterbach.com/scripts.html (search there for "capi" or "python")

For Windows there is t32api.dll and t32api64.dll. For Linux there is t32api.so or t32api64.so. (t32api64.* is for a 64-bit python interpreter, while t32api.* is for a 32-bit python interpreter.)

In the following I assume that you place the t32api-library at the same directory than your python script.

**3. Load the t32api library in your python script**

```
import platform
import ctypes

ostype = ctypes.sizeof(ctypes.c_voidp) * 8
if (platform.system()=='Windows') or (platform.system()[0:6]=='CYGWIN') :
    # WINDOWS
    t32api = ctypes.CDLL("./t32api64.dll" if ostype==64 else "./t32api.dll")
elif platform.system()=='Darwin' :
    # Mac OS X
    t32api = ctypes.CDLL("./t32api.dylib")
else :
    # Linux
    t32api = ctypes.CDLL("./t32api64.so" if ostype==64 else  "./t32api.so")
```

In the t32api-library is not at the same directory than your python script, you have to adapt the paths of course.

**4. Connect via the t32api library to your TRACE32 GUI**

```
# Declare UDP/IP socket of the TRACE32 instance to access
t32api.T32_Config(b"NODE=",b"localhost")
t32api.T32_Config(b"PORT=",b"20000")

# Connect to TRACE32
error = t32api.T32_Init()
if error != 0 :
    sys.exit("Can't connect to TRACE32!")

# Select to debugger component of TRACE32 (B:: prompt)
t32api.T32_Attach(1)
```

If you've chosen another port in step 1, you have to change the line `t32api.T32_Config(b"PORT=",b"20000")` accordingly.

**5. Declare the parameter types of T32_WriteMemory**

```
t32api.T32_WriteMemory.argtypes = [ctypes.c_uint32, ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_char_p, ctypes.c_int]
t32api.T32_WriteMemory.restype  = ctypes.c_int
```

The first line tells python that T32_WriteMemory is a C-function which has four parameters with the types *uint32_t*, *int*, *char** and *int*.
The second line tells python that the return value is of type *int*.

**6. Create a byte buffer with the data to write in your target endianness**

```
wdata = 0x12345678  # <- Your own value here !
wbuffer = wdata.to_bytes(4, byteorder='little')
```

Here, 0x12345678 is the value I have choose to write. My target CPU, which I debug via TRACE32, has it's memory organized in little-endian byte-order. So I've chosen "byteorder='little'" in the second line which creates the byte-buffer.

**7. Call the T32_WriteMemory from the t32api library**

```
# Set parameters for the memory access
byteAddress = 0x46c8  # <- Your address here !
access      = 0x20
byteSize    = 4  # amount of bytes to write (e.g. 4 bytes)

# Write data to memory via TRACE32
error = t32api.T32_WriteMemory(byteAddress, access, wbuffer, byteSize)
if error != 0 :
    print("write failed")
```

`access = 0x20` enables memory access while the CPU is running (if SYStem.MemAccess is enabled in TRACE32 and the CPU supports run-time access) Set it to 0 otherwise, or see the TRACE32 API documentation (api_remote.pdf) for other values.

**8. Close connection to TRACE32 before ending your script**

```
t32api.T32_Exit()
```

---

Reading memory goes like this:

```
# Declare argument types of T32_T32_ReadMemory
t32api.T32_T32_ReadMemory.argtypes = [ctypes.c_uint32,ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_char_p,ctypes.c_int]
t32api.T32_T32_ReadMemory.restype  = ctypes.c_int

# Create a buffer for the result
rbuffer = ctypes.create_string_buffer(byteSize)

# Request memory content via TRACE32
error = t32api.T32_ReadMemory(byteAddress, access, rbuffer, byteSize)
if error == 0 :
  # Extract 32-bit value in little endian order from the buffer
  data32 = int.from_bytes(rbuffer[0:4], byteorder='little')
  print("read  0x%08X from D:0x%08X" % (data32, byteAddress))
else:
  print("read failed")
```