# trace32 python api read memory address - how?

Tags: python, python-3.x, memory, trace32

I am trying to use a python script to read from memory through trace32. I've found the following document: https://www2.lauterbach.com/pdf/api_remote.pdf

I managed the following code:

```
local_buffer = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_uint32)
t32api.T32_ReadMemory(byteAddress=addr, access=0x0, buffer=local_buffer, size=size)
print(local_buffer)
```

Of course there is an initialization of the t32api object - that works. But the code I pasted here causes the following python error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<path_to_python_script>", line 599, in <module>
    main()
  File "<path_to_python_script>", line 590, in main
    process()
  File "<path_to_python_script>", line 269, in process
    NumberOfEmpr = read_addr(0xf0083100)
  File "<path_to_python_script>", line 148, in read_addr
    return read_addr_t32(addr, size)
  File "<path_to_python_script>", line 137, in read_addr_t32
    t32api.T32_ReadMemory(byteAddress=addr, access=0x0, buffer=local_buffer, size=size)
OSError: exception: access violation writing 0xXXXXXXXX
```

Of course 0xXXXXXXXX is a placeholder to some address, I am guessing it is the address of `local_buffer`.

If anyone knows how to fix this I will be thankful.

Comment: Here is a guide how to *write* to memory via the classic remote API from Python: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47717395/4727717  (Reading goes basically the same way and is briefly shown in the bottom of the answer.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the buffer pointer you give to `T32_ReadMemory()` should not only be a pointer but should be a pointer to existing memory.

So you need to change

```
local_buffer = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_uint32)
t32api.T32_ReadMemory(byteAddress=addr, access=0x0, buffer=local_buffer, size=size)
print(local_buffer)
```

to

```
local_buffer = (ctypes.c_ubyte * size)()
t32api.T32_ReadMemory(byteAddress=addr, access=0x0, buffer=local_buffer, size=size)
print(local_buffer)
```

Two remarks independent of your problem:

1. I would suggest to use T32_ReadMemoryObj() instead of T32_ReadMemory().
2. Check [trace32_and_python.pdf](https://www.lauterbach.com/publications/trace32_and_python.pdf). New TRACE32 version include a Python module which you can just import.

Comment: I wish I had this new TRACE32 version. Looks like it would have made life much easier.

Comment: Also, can you add an example of how to use T32_ReadMemoryObj()? I tried it but couldn't figure out how to use it.

Comment: There are C examples on how to use it in api_remote.pdf (or api_remote_c.pdf). If you have any problems post your code in a new question and I'll try to help you.

Comment: I know about those examples, I just don't know how to "translate" them to python. Especially the internal t32 objects. Anyway I'll post a new question.